# Is $\mu$ finitely additive, countably additive, or countably subadditive?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

For any set $A\subset \mathbb{N}$, define a set function $\mu(A)=\sum_{n\in A}2^{-n}$ if $A$ is finite subset otherwise $\mu(A)=\infty$.

Is $\mu$ finitely additive, countably additive, or countably subadditive?

---

It is finitely additive because for two disjoint subsets $A, B$, we have $A\cup B$ is finite and
$$
\mu(A\cup B)=\sum_{n\in A\cup B}2^{-n}=\sum_{n\in A}2^{-n}+\sum_{n\in B}2^{-n}=\mu(A)+\mu(B)
$$

But how about the another cases?

Comment: Hello. I think you need to show a bit more for finite additivity - it's not true that for any two disjoint subsets $A, B \subseteq \Bbb N$, the union $A \cup B$ must be finite. For countable additivity: what's the simplest infinite sequence of disjoint non-empty subsets of $\Bbb N$ that you can think of? Does countable additivity hold for that sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not countably additive since $\mu(\mathbb{N}) = \infty$ but taking $A_n = \{n\}$, we have $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup_n A_n$ and the $A_n$ are disjoint, but $\sum \mu(A_n) < \infty$. This also shows that $\mu$ is not countably subadditive.

You correctly state that it is finitely additive, but you have to take more care in treating the cases where $A$, $B$, or both are infinite sets.

Comment: Do you mean discuss the case that $A\cup B$ is finite or infinite? But if $A\cup B$ is infinite, we do not have the equality $\mu(A\cup B)=\infty$ but $\mu(A)+\mu(B)<\infty$?

Comment: So $\mu(A_n)=2^{-n}$? Then $\sum \mu(A_n)=1$?

Comment: @Hermi if you $A \cup B$ is infinte then one of the two must be infinite as well../

Comment: I just confused that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $A\cup B$ could be infinite? How about this case?

Comment: If $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$ then $|A\cup B| \leq m+n$, so the union of finite sets is finite.

Comment: So what does the comment by @ Izaak van Dongen mean? He is wrong, right?

Comment: He is correct when he says that for two disjoint subsets $A,B \subset \mathbb{N}$, the union is not necessarily finite. This is because $A$ and $B$ are not themselves necessarily finite. If we assume that they are, in fact, both finite, then the union will also be finite. In your original post, you implicitly assumed that $A$ and $B$ are both finite. This is what @Izaak van Dongen is pointing out.